# How to set TV Services Extension TVContentItem badgeCount

Tags: swift, tvos, badge, apple-tv, tvcontentitem

I've added a TV Services Extension target to my project and I'm displaying an `.Inset` `topShelfStyle` like so:

```
var topShelfStyle: TVTopShelfContentStyle {
    return .Inset
}

var topShelfItems: [TVContentItem] {
    let contentIdentifier = TVContentIdentifier(identifier: "Content", container: nil)!
    let contentItem = TVContentItem(contentIdentifier: contentIdentifier)!
    contentItem.badgeCount = 5
    contentItem.title = ""
    contentItem.imageURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("InsetTopShelfImage", withExtension: "png")
    return [contentItem]
}
```

The issue is `.badgeCount` is never set. This is the result I receive:

[image]

The docs seem pretty straight forward on this, [TVContentItem Class Reference: badgeCount](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/TVServices/Reference/TVContentItem_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/TVContentItem/badgeCount), but I've had no success.

**How do I display the** `badgeCount` **on a** `TVContentItem`**?**

---

I've also tried this with a `.Sectioned` `topShelfStyle` and received the same result:

```
var topShelfStyle: TVTopShelfContentStyle {
    return .Sectioned
}

var topShelfItems: [TVContentItem] {
    let contentIdentifier = TVContentIdentifier(identifier: "Content", container: nil)!
    let contentItem = TVContentItem(contentIdentifier: contentIdentifier)!
    contentItem.badgeCount = 5
    contentItem.title = "Title"

    let anotherContentIdentifier = TVContentIdentifier(identifier: "Another Content", container: nil)!
    let anotherContentItem = TVContentItem(contentIdentifier:anotherContentIdentifier)!
    anotherContentItem.badgeCount = 10
    anotherContentItem.imageURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("InsetTopShelfImage", withExtension: "png")

    contentItem.topShelfItems = [anotherContentItem]

    return [contentItem]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add a UILabel where you want and increment it as the number of items increase?

Comment: @Dershowitz123 that is not possible.